# Android JW Player issue

Tags: android, android-videoview, jwplayer, .mov

I had implement JW Player in android, but getting black screen when video load from live URL.

**My HTML file**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/WcmD+p3DEeKQvCIACpYGxA.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id='my-video'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('my-video').setup({
file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/lWMJeVvV-364767.mp4',
image: 'http://www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-876.jpg',
width: '320',
height: '180'
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**and my Java Code is**

```
myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

myBrowser.loadUrl("http://. . . /hardik/jwplayerhtml.html");

what is wrong with me? Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a ink to where this is being run?

Comment: you can put above HTML to asset folder and load by loadUrl("file:///android_asset/jwplayerhtml.html");

Comment: If you do that, does it work?